# Is git reset --hard <ref> safe in detached head

Tags: git

Is safe to `git reset --hard <ref>` in detached HEAD mode (not considering uncommited changes)? AFAIK, all this does is point the HEAD to the ref and checking out the index and working tree, just like `git checkout <commit>` would, and same sandbox thing still applies. Is this correct? So there is no danger, as long as no branch tip is moved, right? And this wouldn't happen in detached HEAD mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a detached HEAD then only the HEAD is moved to the `<ref>`. If you have a branch checked out then it moves the branch to that state as well.

One thing to note is that no commits are actually deleted, they may no longer be visible with a normal `git log` command - but unless you do a `git gc --prune` (git clean) or something then you will still be able to get to the commits that you started at before your reset command was issued with commands like `git fsck --lost-found` and `git log --walk-reflogs --oneline --decorate`...  i.e. git never really deletes anything unless you force it to.